# Flipclock.js automatic countdown when timer done

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, flipclock

I need to create automatic countdown timer to date.
I get from php current date and time and add 4 hours and 4 days, but timer start again when i refresh page. 
How i can made it go to needed day and hour and when it done - go to next date from now.

My code on wordpress -

```
<?php  $date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+4 days');
$date->modify('+4 hours');
 ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[flipclock countdown="true" face="hours" lang="ru" date="'.$date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s').'"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Try to use a Cookie.
 
Check this out:
[Flipclock js countdown 1hour without reset][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670979/flipclock-js-countdown-1hour-without-reset

Comment: I need count to date, if user enter the site first time he see "99:59" because his cookie are empty and timer start, and i want if user enter first time he see real time to real date, but when its date end timer refresh automatic.